# Error: Expected method to read array element not found on object of type "TableItem *"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath ];
    TableItem *item = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.description;
}
```

Error: Expected method to read array element not found on object of type "TableItem *" on this line:  `TableItem *item = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];`

TableItem.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableItem : NSObject

@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *description;

-(instancetype) initWithTitle: (NSString *) title description: (NSString *) description;

@end
```

Comment: what is items ? is it two dimensional array?

Comment: The line with the problem will only work if `self.items` is an `NSArray` and each object in the array is another `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
TableItem *item = self.items[indexPath.row];
```

instead of

```
TableItem *item = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

Here i am assuming is self.items is an array of TableItem object.